# Tomcat starts and then crashes unless I make a call

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I've been beating my head on this issue all day.

I have a simple Web service.  It listens for incoming requests and then performs them.  It's a java app that loads a dll and then performs various tasks based on requests.  On tomcat startup I can see it initialize my single service.  In the constructor of the object I can make calls to the dll and everything seems great.  Then tomcat gives the all clear, deployment in 5.42 sec.  If I hurry and make a request to the webservice, then everything is fine.  The service is then stable and all is well, I could walk away for 2 hours come back and make another call and it would fulfill the request no problems.

If however if I make no requests for 12 seconds (usually though sometimes it takes longer like 2 min) then tomcat inexplicably dies and no services of any kind can be reached.

I could supply web.xml and all sorts of other code if needed but they are all simple.  It seems to be something I'm not understanding at a fundamental level?  I've also scoured for hours looking at all logs everywhere an there is no clue that I could find.

I'm open to any suggestions?  hoping someone else has run into this issue?

I get the same behavior on Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8.

Comment: I suggest that you are not storing a reference to something (whatever is holding your dll) and that garbage collection is cleaning it up. If sending a request through stops this you may be storing a reference during the request processing or in a session that is not expiring.

Comment: The "loads a dll" bit of your question is mildly unsettling. All bets are off when you step outside the JVM